# Google map view color error

Tags: swift, google-maps

I would like to change marker position if button tapped. I tried like below. but it will look like this. Some how color will be changed to like so.
How can I fix this? Thank you!

[image]

```
@objc func changeMarker() {
        let next = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.730610, -73.935242)
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: next.latitude, longitude: next.longitude, zoom: 13)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: next)
        marker.title = "over here"
        marker.map = mapView
    }
```

Comment: Are you changing the marker's position or are you removing the current marker and adding a new one? Because in your example, the marker is not an instance property and so my guess is that you are not changing the same marker.

Comment: Map starts with current location. And if button was tapped, I want map to center that location with marker just like google map app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this marker and try this

```
    func addMarker() {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(yourCoordinateLatitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(yourCoordinateLongitude))
        marker.map = mapView
    }
```

Now you can zoom to your marker

```
func zoomToCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, zoom: Float) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(1, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: zoom)
        self.animate(to: camera)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

I would call it like this

```
mapView.clear() // to clear your mapView
mapView.addMarker()
mapView.zoomToCoordinate(coordinate: yourCoordinate, zoom: 15)
```

Always check if your function is called and if the coordinations are correct.

This code works in my project. If it doesn't work for your project please share more code from you.

Comment: mapView.clear() is necessary? Because I don’t want other markers disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it's not:(

Comment: Then you have to share more code please. The code is working in my project. Is every method called? Does it work with the clean?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I typed wrong longitude. So that blue is sea color. I typed New York in the question above for the sake of easy understanding. In my actual code I should have set 135 but I mistakenly set to 35. so sorry.